# sound .wav clip on ubuntu 21.10 with openjdk 17

Tags: audio, java

I'm trying to play a `.wav` file on my Raspberry Pi (4).
My OS is Ubuntu 21.10, 64 bit.
My JDK is Open JDK 17.0.1.
I've downloaded a sample `.wav` file to play it.
The `.wav` file located under `resources` directory on my Maven project.
I've tried to play it on my MacBook and Windows 10 and I didn't encounter any problem there, it played well. when I tried to play iy on my Raspberry Pi (it is connected via HDMI to my TV and in general it plays sound from anywhere else so the connection is fine) and there was no sound.
Here is the code I wrote:

```java
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        try (Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
             AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/Somebody That I Used To Know.wav")))))
        {
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            System.out.println("Playing...");
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I've formatted my Raspberry Pi and tried again with no success.
can anyone come to the rescue?

Comment: Does the file play if you double click it?

Comment: @user68186 yes... the file is fine

Comment: @user68186 I've checked it on my Raspberry Pi, and it played through the HDMI output just fine